# How do I create / access dynamic form fields in Django from within a View?

Tags: python, django, forms, dynamic, view

I have a system which keeps lots of "records" and need to integrate a component which will produce reports of any selected records.

To the user, it looks like this:

1. Click "Create Report"
2. Select the records to be included in the report.
3. Hit "Submit" and the report is displayed.

To me I think:

1. Load all records.
2. Create a ReportForm which produces a "BooleanField" by iterating over all of the records from part 1 and using code like: self.fields['cid_' + str(record.id)] = BooleanField()
3. Return the HTML, expect it back.
4. Iterate over all of the fields beginning with 'cid_' and create a list of record ids to be included in the report.
5. Pass the numbers to the report generator.

But from within the view I cannot access the form data the only way I can imagine doing it. Since I don't know which Record IDs will be available (since some may have been deleted, etc) I need to access it like this:

{{form.fields['cid_'+str(record.id)']}}

But apparently this is illegal.

Does anybody have some suggestions?

Comment: To make sure I understand: So you want to select from a list of records to be included in the report, but you can't simply query through these records because some may be deleted, etc in the time from when you load the page to when you begin the report?

You can easily create a simple form that will list (as checkboxes for example) all the records .. if you can inform me exactly what you want I may be able to help a little more.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do -- create a form that will list all of the records as checkboxes. But I can't just do "form.as_p" because I have specific formatting I want to use, so I don't know which fields I can access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your answer lies in using the proper Django form widgets. I will give you an example. Let's say you have a Django model: -

```
class Record(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

Let's say you create a custom Form for your needs: -

```
class MyCustomForm(forms.Form):
    records= forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Record.objects.all, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

Let's say you have the following view: -

```
def myview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyCustomForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #do what you want with your data
            print form.cleaned_data['records']
            #do what you want with your data
    else:
        form = MyCustomForm()
    return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Your `mytemplate.html` might look like this: -

```
<div>
    {{ form.records.label_tag }}
    {{ form.records }}
</div>
```